# I have if else loop in my _Layout.cshtml page but, when i try to run it it gives me RenderBody error saying, Renderbody is already called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have attached the code below, please see and i am a newbie to this, it would be so much nice if you post in code, please...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 @model Forecaster.Models.ForecastModel
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>@ViewBag.Title - Forecaster</title>
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 </head>
 <body>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UsersInfoList.Count(); i++)
  {
    <div class="navbar" role="main" style="margin-bottom:-50px;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="~/Images/logo.jpg" alt="Forecaster" style="padding-left:inherit;"></a>
        </div>
        @if ((Model.UsersInfoList[i].RoleId == 1) && (Model.UsersInfoList[i].UserName == Session["UserName"].ToString()))
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Dashboard", "Dashboard")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee", "Index", "EmployeeMasters")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Project", "Index", "ProjectMasters")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Export", "ExportToExcel", "Dashboard")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right; padding-right:59px;">
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "UserDashboard", "Login")
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @if (Session["UserName"] != null)
                    {<text>@Session["UserName"].ToString() </text> }
                </a>
            </p>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Dashboard", "Dashboard")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Project", "Index", "ProjectMasters")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right; padding-right:59px;">
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "UserDashboard", "Login")
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @if (Session["UserName"] != null)
                    {<text>@Session["UserName"].ToString() </text> }
                </a>
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:45px;">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <div class="col-lg-pull-10">
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
}
```

Please anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? i need to authorize the user and renderbody in both cases!
Thankyou!

Comment: Why is Scripts.Render, RenderBody, and RenderSection in a foreach loop?  Even if you remove RenderBody from it, these other sections will be problematic...

Comment: what do you suggest @BrianMains

Comment: Pull all of that out of the for loop - what's the purpose of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have RenderBody inside a FOR loop...

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.UsersInfoList.Count(); i++)
```

Are you sure Model.UsersInfoList has only one record in it?

Comment: Well that explains it... at the moment you are calling RenderBody once for each object in that list.... (also rendering the Scripts section multiple times). So you want to close your for loop earlier in the page

Comment: Out of interest... Why would you have multiple users? doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Oh - you are searching all users in the view and comparing to session to see if they are the logged in users? This is a TERRIBLE idea. Please populate your UsersInfoList in the controller with ONLY the logged in user

Comment: okay, thanks for the explanation i guess i have to do something about the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You're for loop goes all the way to the end, so @RenderBody is produced more than once.

Answer (score -2):

your below section should be out from the foreach loop.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:45px;">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <div class="col-lg-pull-10">
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```